# SQL - Selecting rows based on priority level

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Given the following two tables:

PRODUCT_CATEGORIES

```
PRODUCT_CATEGORY    PRIOTITY

BOOK               100
VIDEO              200
CD                 300
```

PRODUCT_TYPES

```
PRODUCT_TYPE_ID PRODUCTID   PRODUCT_CATEGORY
1               1001        VIDEO
2               1001        CD
3               1002        BOOK
4               1002        VIDEO
5               1003        BOOK
```

How can i join the two tables so that i select all the rows from PRODUCT_TYPES and where there are duplicate products i only select the one with the highest priority.

For example, for PRODUCTID 1002, i only want the row with a category of VIDEO because VIDEO has a higher priority than BOOK (which is the category of the other 1002 product in the table).

Here is what i have tried but i only seem to get duplicates.

```
select product_type_id, productid, product_category
from product_types pt
join product_categories pc on (pc.product_category=pt.product_category)
```

One other way of doing it is to order by product_category in descending order and select the first row where rownum=1 but i suspect that is not the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH recordList 
AS
(
    SELECT  a.Product_TypeID,
            a.ProductID,
            a.Product_Category,
            b.Priority,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProductID
                                ORDER BY b.Priority) RN
    FROM    Product_Types a
            INNER JOIN Product_Categories b
                ON a.Product_Category = b.Product_Category
)
SELECT      Product_TypeID,
            ProductID,
            Product_Category,
            Priority
FROM    recordList
WHERE   RN = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/487fa1/2)

Comment: Yes it was very helpful. I had to read up on how PARTITION BY works. Quick question - Why are you selecting RN = 1? Should it not be selecting the row with the highest row number? Or should the order by clause be in descending order for RN=1 to be correct?

Comment: it should be `PARTITION BY a.ProductID
                                ORDER BY b.Priority DESC` `:D`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following query:

```
 SELECT PT.*
 FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORIES PC INNER JOIN PRODUCT_TYPES PT
 ON PC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY = PT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
 WHERE PC.PRIOTITY = (
 SELECT MAX(PRIOTITY) FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORIES IPC
   , PRODUCT_TYPES IPT
   WHERE IPC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY = IPT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
     AND IPT.PRODUCTID = PT.PRODUCTID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
   product_type_id,
   productid,
   product_category
from
   PRODUCT_TYPES
where
   product_type_id in (
      select
         max(product_type_id) keep (dense_rank first order by priotity desc)
      from 
         PRODUCT_TYPES
         join PRODUCT_CATEGORIES using(product_category)
      group by 
         productid
   )
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bcee/2)